# Service to receive SMS messages from short codes?

Tags: twilio, sms, vonage, plivo, callfire

So I need to programmatically receive text messages from a shortcode. Twilio does not support this. Anybody know a service like Twilio but that is able to receive SMS messages from a short code sender?

Just to be clear. I need to receive a text message from a shortcode to a **10 digit number**, not send from a shortcode.
Most services (Twilio, call fire) that let you send from a shortcode can not receive a text message from a shortcode

Answer (score 1):

This can’t be done, shortcodes are unique to each carrier network, when a short code is available across multiple carriers it is implemented on each carrier separatly.
Also shortcodes are not international so 54321 could be used in both the UK and US by totally separate services.

SMS providers like Twilio and Vonage connect to the carriers in the same way as the shortcodes do, they are both an application connection. The carriers do not permit app to app messaging through their network so a shortcode app will only ever be able to send to a real subscriber with a SIM card.

You might find some providers that offer an SMS API by using banks of hosted SIM cards but this can be very flakey and you are usually sharing the number. The other option might be to look at hosting your own SIM card in a usb single or such and recieve the SMS that way.

Comment: "Shortcodes" not always needed to be short. It can be regular number which at operator trigers AT (application termination). In that case, other carrier subcribers can send to this number which will be forwarded to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Twillio does support this now, although with a big disclaimer that it "cannot guarantee that every short code globally will be able to reach Twilio numbers"

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181668-Can-Twilio-numbers-receive-SMS-from-a-short-code-?_ga=2.202438166.641482548.1608644940-210958917.1588771372

Answer (score -1):

I think this article might be just what you're looking for https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/216487658-Inbound-SMS-on-dedicated-US-short-code

You should be able to receive SMS messages on a dedicated US Shortcode.

Comment: No luck . I got a  10 digit trial number from Nexmo and sent short code sms to the number through my application. But Nexmo number didn't receive

Comment: Nexmo numbers can’t receive messages from other Nexmo numbers, it’s a fraud concern. You should be able to receive a message on a short code from a real number (see referenced article)